# How to fix PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_ssl()

Tags: php, fatal-error

I am getting:

> "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function is_ssl()"

Because of this, I think I can't login in my admin page.

I tried to write a code for a plugin to redirect me when it is used the Server HTTP_host but i couldn't activate the plugin.

```
if ( is_ssl() ) {
if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {
    wp_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
    exit();
} else {
    wp_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    exit();
  } 
}
```

> "Call to undefined function is_ssl()" ;
>
> "Call to undefined function force_ssl_admin()"

Comment: Please share more details. PHP does not have such a function built in

Answer (score 0):

`is_ssl()` is located in `wp-includes/load.php`.
For versions of WordPress prior to `4.6.0`, it was located in `wp-includes/functions.php`.

Check the integrity of these files

Comment: is_ssl() is located in wp-login.php.

Comment: The function is called in `wp-login.php`. The function itself should be in the specified files.